# Objective-c, Which is better AVPlayer or MPMovieplayer for play video from URL?

Tags: ios, iphone, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

I want to play video from URL.  I found some player like avplayer and  mpmovieplayer for play video. But I have no idea which is better. Please let me know which will be better for me. (avplayer or mpmovieplayer or any other player ) I have no requirement to play multiple video.I have to play single video at at time. any suggestion will be great. Thanks in advance !!!!!!!!

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated from IOS 9 and so you should use AVPlayer for future projects

Answer (score 2):

MpMoviePlayer Controller would be the best option for video 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/

and AVPlayer is the best option for playing audio not video
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/

My recommendation is MPMoviePlayerController i have used it multiple videostream projects.Thanks

Comment: Thanks @ baydi . Did you use and experience of  both MpMoviePlayer and AVPlayer (play video from URL) ??

Comment: Yes i have used both MpMoviePlayerController for Video and AVPlayer for Audio

Comment: I think MpMoviePlayerController Supported only these formats :   .mov ,  .mpv ,  .3gp and .mp4 . So is there any other good video player (play video from URL) which support more or maximum formats . Thanks in advance !!!!!!

Comment: Can you show the url of any video?

Comment: Sure Have a look please :  https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t50.2886-16/11719145_918467924880620_816495633_n.mp4     and https://mmv247.whatsapp.net/d/_H0YkIjZtSE8KoPl6LHoPlXpRjc/AvTsykDaSg65E-ri-4K84S8esHEjQLjXoC8gaC4Pg6lp.mp4  and  http://download.itcuties.com/teaser/itcuties-teaser-480.mp4#sthash.R4MKfTeJ.dpuf

Comment: If .pduf file doesnot work on MpMovieplayer than try this link using UIWebView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88788/discussion-between-monu-singh-and-baydi).